# Given vertex and a point, how to solve the coefficient?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose that we have a vector $x$ that lies in a polytope $C$, and we know the vertexes of the polytope $v=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$.

$x$ can be expressed as a convex combination of the vertexes, i.e. $x=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$ where $a_i\geq 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=1$. How can we get $a_i$? Are there any tools to do this?

I tried to express the condition as a linear equation and solved it. However, I can not force the solution to be greater than $0$ which leads to a bizarre solution.

Comment: Other than solving with an LP, nothing comes to mind.